# 7zip command line - recursively unzipping all zipped files

Tags: recursion, command-line, extract, 7zip

I have 7zip on my desktop computer, at:  c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe.  I also have 2 mapped drives that have similar structures, drive X and drive Y. Below is an example of the source.

```
Drive X
X:\Sourcefolder\Folder1\file1.zip
X:\Sourcefolder\Folder1\file2.zip
X:\Sourcefolder\Folder2\file3.zip
X:\Sourcefolder\Folder3\file4.zip
```

The destination folder structure would be as follows:

```
Drive Y
Y:\DestFolder\Thing1\Folder1\[file1.zip contents and subfolders]
Y:\DestFolder\Thing1\Folder1\[file2.zip contents and subfolders]
Y:\DestFolder\Thing1\Folder2\[file3.zip contents and subfolders]
Y:\DestFolder\Thing1\Folder3\[file4.zip contents and subfolders]
```

The folders on Drive Y (DestFolder\Thing1\Folder1, 2 & 3) are already created.  Some of them may already have other files & subfolders in them.

I can run the following command line and unzip the contents:

```
for /R %i IN (*.zip) DO "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%i" -o"Y:\DestFolder\Thing1\Folder1"
```

However, what happens is that on my mapped drive, I see a **NEW** structure out there that is exactly what I had in the second set of quotes in the command line, even if those folders already existed.  Thus far, I've only tested it on empty folders, as I am concerned it might corrupt any existing files that would be there.  I can navigate between them, and can cut & paste the files into the correct folder.

Why is 7zip "creating" the duplicate folder structure to extract the files into?  I know the `-o` switch allows you to specify a destination directory, but it doesn't say in the help file that it creates it or what happens if it already exists.

Should I be using another command line parameter to extract these zip files into the proper folders?  Thanks!